# jquery - working with event handlers

Tags: jquery, event-handling, mouseevent

First up... Thank-you in advance!

- I have 4 divs.
- When each div is rolled-over i want divs with unique text to appear within another div that has a class name of '.rollOversHolder'
- The text divs all contain an id of '#copy' but all have unique class names eg. '.copy1', '.copy2' etc
- I want the '#copy' divs to be individually displayed within the '.rollOversHolder' div and when another button is rolled over i want to current animation to stop and the new one begin.

HTML ---

```
<div class="rollOversHolder">
        <div id="main1" class="rollOver_1"></div>
        <div id="main1" class="rollOver_2"></div>
        <div id="main1" class="rollOver_3"></div>
        <div id="main1" class="rollOver_4"></div>                  
</div>

<div class="emptyCopyClass"></div>

<div id="copy" class="copy1">
    Test text _01
</div>
<div id="copy" class="copy2">
    Test text _02
</div>
<div id="copy" class="copy3">
    Test text _03
</div>
<div id="copy" class="copy4">
    Test text _04
</div>
```

jQuery -----

```
  function slideDownFunc() {
        if(jQuery("#copy.copy1")){
            if (jQuery("#copy.copy1").is(":hidden")) {
                jQuery("#copy.copy1").stop().slideUp("medium");
            }
        }else if(jQuery("#copy.copy1")){
            jQuery("#copy.copy1").stop().slideUp("medium");
        }
    };

    function slideUpFunc() {
        if(jQuery("#copy.copy2")){
            if (jQuery("#copy.copy2").is(":visible")) {
                jQuery("#copy.copy2").stop().slideDown("medium");
            }
        }else if(jQuery("#copy.copy2")){
            jQuery("#copy.copy2").stop().slideDown("medium");
        }
    };

jQuery("#main1.rollOver_1").mouseover(function(){
        slideDownFunc();
    }).mouseout(function(){
        slideUpFunc();
});

jQuery("#main1.rollOver_2").mouseout(function(){
        slideDownFunc();
    }).mouseout(function(){
        slideUpFunc();
});
```

CSS ----------

```
.rollOversHolder {
    width:710px;
    height:135px;
    border:#CCCCCC 1px solid;
}

#main1 {
    background:url(../images/it_sol_norm.png);
    width:103px;
    height:133px;
    float:left;
}

.emptyCopyClass {
    width:230px;
    height:150px;
    position:relative;
    color:#4d4d4d;
    border:1px solid red;
}

#copy {
    width:230px;
    height:150px;
    position:relative;
    display:none;
    color:#4d4d4d;
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific and tell us whether you are having problems with above code or you need some optimization or you are trying to fix certain issue?

Comment: You can't use the same ID more than once on a page.

Comment: You're going to have trouble right off the bat as you have several divs with the same id. Also, you're referring to the selector `#leftCopy1` and `#leftCopy2` in your jQuery, but they don't exist in the HTML you've provided.

Comment: perhaps if you can make it working on jsfiddle.net, so it would be more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

I have set the rollOversHolder to wrap around hover copy, set same dimensions to one hover-able content set. Set all items to position absolute so that animation can occur on 1 set location. on animation i am setting the z-index to show relative content.

Check the following: http://jsfiddle.net/aP2r3/8/

**HTML**

```
<div class="rollOversHolder">
    <div id="main1" class="rollOver_1 rollover">test1</div>
    <div id="main2" class="rollOver_2 rollover">test2</div>
    <div id="main3" class="rollOver_3 rollover">test3</div>
    <div id="main4" class="rollOver_4 rollover">test4</div>                  
</div>

<div class="rollOversHolder">

    <div id="Copy1" class="copy1 copy">
        01
    </div>
    <div id="Copy2" class="copy2 copy">
        02
    </div>
    <div id="Copy3" class="copy3 copy">
        03
    </div>
    <div id="Copy4" class="copy4 copy">
        04
    </div>

</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(function() {
    var curI = 0;
    jQuery(".rollover").hover(function() {

        //index() gets index value started from 0 - Id values starts from 1, that's why the + 1.
        curI = $(this).index() + 1;

        //Set all hover copy to lower layer of display
        $('.copy').css('z-index', '1');

        //Set hovered copy to higher layer of display
        $('#Copy' + curI).css('z-index', '100');

        //Set dimension again, coz stop() animation may reset original dimensions
        $('.copy').css('width', '103px');
        $('.copy').css('height', '133px');

        //Stop all animation and slideDown the hovered Item
        $('#Copy' + curI).stop().slideDown(500);


    }, function() {

        //Set hovered copy to higher layer of display
        $('.copy').css('z-index', '1');

        //Stop all animation and slideUp to last item on mouse out
        $('#Copy' + curI).stop().slideUp(500);

    });


});
```

Please let me know if this is working for you.

**UPDATE [click event]**

You can have a look at this : http://jsfiddle.net/aP2r3/9/

For a click event, see my following code (You can just change the class names to be more relevant)

Jquery :

```
$(function() {
    var curI = 0;
    jQuery(".rollover").click(function() {

        //index() gets index value started from 0 - Id values starts from 1, that's why the + 1.
        curI = $(this).index() + 1;

        //Set all hover copy to lower layer of display
        $('.copy').css('z-index', '1');

        //Set hovered copy to higher layer of display
        $('#Copy' + curI).css('z-index', '100');

        //Set dimension again, coz stop() animation may reset original dimensions
        $('.copy').css('width', '103px');
        $('.copy').css('height', '133px');

        //Hiding all except the relative content and showing the clicked content
        $('.copy:not(#Copy' + curI + ')').stop(true, true).slideUp(500, function() {
            $('#Copy' + curI).slideDown(500);
        })

    });

});
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks again! Sorry but i edited my code.. 
I took a look at your example http://jsfiddle.net/aP2r3/1/
This is very close to what im after although,, when any of the buttons are rolled-over i would like the current effect to immediately stop before the next one begins...?

Comment: Thx, Will make the changes quickly. :)

Comment: I really do appreciate your hasty response.. The code is still a bit  glitchy though, if you scroll over the buttons really fast, 2 sometimes 3 boxes will appear briefly at the same time..? And it also remembers the amount of times that it has been rolled-over and will keep playing the animation long after you have finished hovering...??

Also.. when i copy your jsfiddle code into my own jsfiddle.. it doesnt seem to work at all... I have also created new files that are locally hosted and it still won't work...?

Thanks again, much appreciated !! ;)

Comment: Also could you please explain the following line and how interacts with your js and css:

Comment: Hi Mark,
Ok I have got your code semi work...
I believe the, 'curI = $(this).index() + 1;' line is not working properly. when i take that out and directly reference a div name then the code will work, of course now it will not distinguish what div to display for the appropriate rollOver.. Any suggestions anyone..?

Comment: if you add a   .stop(true, true) to your code then it kills the rollover memory, so as soon as you stop hovering so will the hover effect, no matter how many times it is hovered over.
orig:--
$('#Copy' + curI).slideDown('fast');

$('#Copy' + curI).stop(true, true).slideDown('fast');

Comment: I have updated my answer, I was actually busy using the .stop() function with my new update, thanks. :) Please let me know if my new update works for you.

Comment: Just giving it a try, i'll let you know soon ;)

Comment: I have copied you code into here: http://jsfiddle.net/gavAusWeb/4DPBK/10/
For the moment, it doesn't seem to work.., let me know if that link doesnt work!

Comment: The link doesn't work, coz you have your JS framework set to Mootools, instead of Jquery. FYI you can work on the link I have sent you http://jsfiddle.net/aP2r3/8/ :)

Comment: Sorry my bad... Checking it out now

Comment: Have you tried this in actual documents..? It seems to work in jsFiddle, but not my actual documents.. i have tested the page links (javascript, css etc) and they appear to be all linked properly...

Comment: Give me a link to your actual document, so I can do proper testing and edits... But it should be working fine either way.

Comment: It is not working coz you are including a old jquery version [1.2.6] instead of [1.6.2]. include the latest jquery and it should be fine : http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js

Comment: Ok i have updated my version of jquery with the one you recommended above.. still no go..??

Comment: you can access the actual files here:--- https://www.yousendit.com/dl?phi_action=app/orchestrateDownload&rurl=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.yousendit.com%252Ftransfer.php%253Faction%253Dbatch_download%2526batch_id%253DcnJpRGx6Y1NlM1JjR0E9PQ

Comment: Another bug I found was that the image you are referencing is getting a 404 error. double check your image path and try again . Should be : http://arcadiafm.com.au/rollOver_tests/images/it_sol_norm.png

Comment: Currently your image is trying "/rollOver_tests/src/images/" ...should be withouth the "src/"

Comment: The text should be appearing and disappearing regardless of the images..?

Comment: Hang-on we have movement :P
Now there is a bug that shoots the text down the screen, check out my link to view it, thanks! ;)  http://arcadiafm.com.au/rollOver_tests/test.html

Comment: LoL! First of all, your css file is getting a 404 error. Check in my answer, you have to set a container for your sliding hover items with a fixed width and height. And set your sliding hover items to position:absolute.

Comment: bahahahaha! what a fool i am :P

Comment: I got it !!!! Well you got it lol.. Mark, I can't thank-you enough for all the replies and the time u spent directing my clumsy coding and only hope that one that i may return the favour to a fellow noob like myself!! Thanks again mate!! :D

Comment: I wont close the thread yet as tomorrow i need to develop it a little further an no doubt will hit a spot of trouble :P But consider the first half of the thread ANSWERED !!

Comment: AWESOME! No problem, Cheers, all of the best. :)

Comment: Hey mark, hope all is well! Quick question... How would you achieve the same effect that we were working on yesterday but instead of using a hover, you use a click? so it would need to the following - click 1 of 4 div's, once clicked the appropriate text will appear in another div...

that bit i can do but i cant seem to trigger the buttons to work off each other, so that if any of the other buttons are clicked, the current animation immediately stops animating and plays the new animation, also if  they only could display one at a time no matter how many times hovered..??

Thanks again mate !!

Comment: I have just responded with a new problem, should be pretty easy, i got some of the way on this one.. lol

Comment: Hey gav. Cool, i will change the event to work on click, just busy with something else at the moment, but will post a link shortly :). cheerz bud

Comment: No probs at all!! Look forward to your response, have a great weekend mate ;)

Comment: I have made the changes to my original answer, see UPDATE [click event] for jquery and link. Here is the link anyway : http://jsfiddle.net/aP2r3/9/ . Have a great weekender :)

Comment: Hi gav, please let me know if my updated code is working for you. Thanks

Comment: Remember to mark it as the correct answer ;) Glad I could help. Cheerz bud

Comment: I ticked that it was my favourite answer... is there anything else to tick..??

Comment: Hi Mark, whenever you get 5, I have another question, it should be pretty easy to solve, cheers mate! ;)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906787/jquery-click-activate-active-button

Comment: Thanks gav, I will have a look at you new question in a moment. cheerz

Comment: Great, thanks!! How was ur weekend..?
 Make sure you go down to my last comment, that is the real problem at hand.. ;)

Comment: Was awesome thanks :) you? I am having internet difficulties and can't open jsfiddle to do proper testing, will have a look asap.

Comment: Good to hear! For me, it was a productive one, was working on a flash site for most of it, a job i took out of hours.. But its finished now and the ppl like what i have done so it was all  well worth it! Np's Marc, all good! I look forward to you your reply.. Ps. I finally spelt your name right :P

Comment: Oh yeah, one last thing sorry... I found i couldnt animate the bg-image unless i used the following jquerry plugin: It's called 'backgroundPosition-Effect' that can be found at: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/backgroundPosition-Effect
 Hope that helps !! ;)

Comment: Ps. I wasnt sure how to include the plugin into jsFiddle otherwise i would have set up my own for you to tweak!

Comment: Okay we have to move the discussion to the new question. See answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6906787/jquery-click-activate-active-button

Comment: Hi Marc, just a quick add on to the original question posted on this page... I would also like to set a default-text div,(just like the others) but this one will display when page loads. Just like before when you click the appropriate button it will show the appropriate text, replacing the default text..? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hi, to do this you only have to add to the css e.g to show copy1 : .copy1{display:block;} . So just add display block to the copy you want to show. ;)

Comment: hey mate i hope ur well, just got a quick little problem that if you have time, would be great if you could take a look see.. Thanks mate!

Here is the link.. http://jsfiddle.net/HSbzC/2/

Comment: ***Scenario... Basically I am trying to make the 'accordion' effect, i got most of the way.. but couldnt figure out how I could stop any other divs animating while there is one currently animating...?? Also, if you click the div a few time in a row it will keep animating long after you click.. how can we stop this from happening..?? I played around with adding stop(true,true).. but it doesnt seem to have the right effect. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey buddy, this should fix it : http://jsfiddle.net/HSbzC/4/  ...I am checking if the secretDivs stop animated, then only will the next click work. :)

Comment: Legend !! Thanks again, perfect :)
How's things anyways chief...??

Comment: :) Awesome! Goes great thx. you? Cheerz dude, I'm off to work for now. Have a great one and keep well.