# jquery - click & activate active button

Tags: jquery, animation, rollover, background-position

In jQuery:

Scenario **
 - I have four Divs that have hover effects. 
 - All use a jquery animation to move the backgroundPosition to show the hover state.

Problem **
 - I want to set a focus or clicked state, so that once you have clicked on a button it animates the background position even further to show the new state. I would also like the buttons to be aware if any other buttons have been clicked and remove the current click state and begin to animate the new click state on the new selected button ...??

My efforts **
 - I have done a bit of the coding but cant seem to work out this focus state, thanks again in advance !! ;)

HTML **

```
<div class="rollOversHolderOne">

    <div id="mainServices_01" class="rollOver_1 rollover"></div>

        <div id="mainServices_02" class="rollOver_2 rollover"></div>

        <div id="mainServices_03" class="rollOver_3 rollover"></div>

        <div id="mainServices_04" class="rollOver_4 rollover"></div>

</div>
```

CSS **

```
#mainServices_01 {
    width:103px;
    height:131px;
    float:left;
    background:url(../images/slideHover.png) repeat 0 0;
    background-position: inline;
}
#mainServices_02 {
    width:103px;
    height:131px;
    float:left;
    background:url(../images/slideHover.png) repeat 0 0;
    background-position: inline;
}
#mainServices_03 {
    width:103px;
    height:131px;
    float:left;
    background:url(../images/slideHover.png) repeat 0 0;
    background-position: inline;
}
#mainServices_04 {
    width:103px;
    height:131px;
    float:left;
    background:url(../images/slideHover.png) repeat 0 0;
    background-position: inline;
}
```

jQuery **

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var flag; 
    var active;

    jQuery('.rollover').css( {backgroundPosition: "0 0"} ).click(function(){

        flag = false;

        jQuery(this).stop().animate(
            {backgroundPosition:"(0 -130.5px)"}, 
            {duration:1});

    });


    jQuery('.rollover').mouseout(function(){

        if(flag == false)
        {
            jQuery(this).stop().animate(
            {backgroundPosition:"(0 -130.5px)"}, 
            {duration:1})
        }else{
            jQuery(this).stop().animate(
            {backgroundPosition:"(0 0)"}, 
            {duration:1})
        }
    });


    jQuery('.rollover').mouseover(function(){

            jQuery(this).stop().animate(
            {backgroundPosition:"(0 -130.5px)"}, 
            {duration:1})
            flag = true;
    });

});
```

Comment: @Pablo Fernandez - 
no worries, some of them werent correct though..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var flag; 
    var $active = null;

    jQuery('.rollover').css( {backgroundPosition: "0 0"} ).click(function(){

       if($active && ($active.index() == jQuery(this).index()))
           return;

       if($active){
           $active.stop().animate(
            {backgroundPosition:"(0 0)"}, 
            {duration:1})
       }

       $active = $(this);

        jQuery(this).addClass("clicked").stop().animate(
            {backgroundPosition:"(0 -280px)"}, 
            {duration:1});

    }).mouseout(function(){

    if(!$active || ($active && ($active.index() != jQuery(this).index()))){
        jQuery(this).stop().animate(
        {backgroundPosition:"(0 0)"}, 
        {duration:1})
    }

   }).mouseover(function(){

      if(!$active || ($active && ($active.index() != jQuery(this).index()))){
        jQuery(this).stop().animate(
        {backgroundPosition:"(0 -130.5px)"}, 
        {duration:1})
      }
});

});
```

Comment: That was very close, although it still wont stay on a clicked state, once it has been clicked..? Much appreciated!!

Comment: @av_aus_web - Please try me edited answer it should work fine now.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'll give it a try right now and get back to ya ! ;)

Comment: Sorry but that didnt seem to do anything.. I have mouseOver and mouseOut effects towards the bottom of my code.. would they be conflicting at all..?? I would also like to incorporate the mouseOver, mouseOut & the click so that if a button is selected, then the currButton stops its clicked state and the new one shows its clicked state...?? Kinda confusing, but basically its like a normal css drop down i guess, including: inactive, active & hover states...

Comment: You dont need mouse over/out events if you want to change the state only on click.

Comment: Ok, maybe i have confused everyone here...
 so i have four divs that are buttons with bg-images, when u mouseover them, bg-image 'y' moves 140px, if you mouseout bg-image 'y' will move back to 0px ... if you click then the mouse out will be disable on that button until another button is clicked while at the same time 'y' will move a 280px... Any suggestions..?

Comment: Also atm, no matter how many pixels i specify, the click will force the image all the way to the top instead of proceeding further down to the 3rd state, 'clicked'.

Comment: @gav_aus_web - Please try my edited answer I hope that should solve your problem, thanks.

Comment: Hi ShankarSangoli, that is nearly perfect !! Just one thing, when you click a button, the mouseOut should be disabled for that button unitl another button is clicked, other than that i think it looks pretty much perfect, thanks heaps! ;)

Comment: The code is in place to take care of that. I dont know what is wrong you need to debug and see. Anyways please accept my answer if you think this is the perfect solution thanks

Comment: Hi, check out this link and you will see that the mouseLeave is still active after you click.. http://jsfiddle.net/gavAusWeb/R6bB7/

Comment: There was a silly mistake I fixed it. Take a look at [link](http://jsfiddle.net/R6bB7/3/)

Comment: Thank-you, and nice job! We are getting really close.. Everything in your code works perfectly! But i am also using 'jQuery.noConflict();' mode..  When this is placed into your jsFiddle code, it seems to effect the click options.. Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/gavAusWeb/R6bB7/7/

Comment: That is 100% perfect!! Would be asking too much for a few comments with in the jsFiddle, just to let me know what's going on, that way i can hopefully learn more from it..? I really cant thank-you enough, a fantastic job, thank-you!! :)

Comment: Sure, I love to share my knowledge. I have added the necessary comments in this fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/R6bB7/13/). I hope it will help you understand how it is implemented.

Comment: That was perfect, I really implore your attitude, some forums are very cut-throat.. this is one of the best i have ever come across, ppl actually want to help you, not chop you down at any chance!! Thanks again for all your help and keep up the good work!! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Mxkga/1/

What I have done :

- Check on item hover, animate to first state
- Keep items on first state , once item container is not focused, set
  all items to normal state
- If user clicked an item, set item to second state and reset other
  items to normal state.

Here is the jquery (see above link for working example):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {


    jQuery('.rollover').css({
        backgroundPosition: "0 0"
    }).click(function() {

        //Reset and remove class activeClicked
        jQuery('.rollover').animate({
            backgroundPosition: "(0 0)"
        }, {
            duration: 500
        });
        jQuery('.rollover').removeClass('activeClicked');

        //Set new animate second state for clicked and add class
        jQuery(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundPosition: "(0 -500px)"
        }, {
            duration: 500
        });
        jQuery(this).addClass('activeClicked');
    });

    //Check when item container is not user's focus anymore, and reset all
    jQuery('.rollOversHolderOne').mouseleave(function() {

        jQuery('.rollover').stop().animate({
            backgroundPosition: "(0 0)"
        }, {
            duration: 500
        })

    });

    //If user enters an item, animate background to first state
    jQuery('.rollover').mouseenter(function() {

        jQuery(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundPosition: "(0 -130.5px)"
        }, {
            duration: 500
        })

    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Marc! I added a new class because the mouseLeave wasnt registering for each button, but instead it was registering when you left the holding div, which caused the divs to stay in a hover state if you scroll quickly across a few buttons.. Your thoughts on this, its working, but is it effecient..?

Comment: Also one last thing.. Once clicked, the mouseLeave needs to be de-activated for the clickedButton and only re-activated once another button is clicked...? Thanks again Marc! ;)